# file organization in node.js project

Tags: node.js

When creating a node.js project (express based if it matters),
what is the recommended way to store the different files building up the project?

More specifically, dependent external models (being declared as dependencies in package.json) are downloaded to `./node_modules`, so where should I place my "locally" created modules ?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

See [nodejs-express-mongoose-demo](https://github.com/madhums/nodejs-express-mongoose-demo/). It has the perfect file structure.

Answer (score 0):

the standard is to use a local `lib` directory.

see the node.js libraries on git, there are a million examples.

[Cradle Git](https://github.com/cloudhead/cradle)

[Node2XML Git](https://github.com/Leonidas-from-XIV/node-xml2js)

[Express Source on Git](https://github.com/visionmedia/express)

Comment: Just to make sure I extrapulate corectly from the examples:
locally written code goes under lib. single file modules directly under lib and if a module requires additional files it should have a folder of its own under lib ?